# Why does const_cast need to state what you're casting to?

Tags: c++, casting, standards

According to the standard (§5.2.11) a const_cast casts away cv-qualifiers (const or volatile).

Here's a simple example. First you declare two functions taking a pointer and a reference:

```
class Bar { ... };
void foo_ptr(Bar*);
void foo_ref(Bar&);
```

then you create a reference-to-const:

```
Bar b;
const Bar& cb = b;
```

and then you can call either function by using the appropriate const_cast:

```
foo_ptr(const_cast<Bar*>(&cb));
foo_ref(const_cast<Bar&>(cb));
```

Here's my question: since const_cast cannot do what the other casts were designed for, isn't it obvious what you're casting to? In other words, why doesn't the language allow me to simply say:

```
foo_ptr(const_cast<>(&cb));
foo_ref(const_cast<>(cb));
```

I can think of only the following two reasons:

a) The compiler should stop me when I try to do something crazy, like:

```
foo_ptr(const_cast<int*>(&cb));
foo_ref(const_cast<int&>(cb));
```

and by forcing me to explicitly state the type I'm casting to it can then keep me from misbehaving. I find this (hypothetical) explanation weak, since it would be bizarre if the language favored allowing me to write down something wrong only to have the compiler correct me.

b) There is a possible ambiguity if the variable is both const and volatile. In that case the compiler would have no way of telling if I'm trying to cast away the one or the other (or both).

Is that why, or is there another reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const_cast` can be used to add *or remove* `const` and `volatile` qualifiers.  So, if such a syntax were allowed, all of the following would be legitimate target types of `const_cast<>(&cb)`:

```
Bar*                 (1)
const Bar*           (2)
volatile Bar*        (3)
const volatile Bar*  (4)
```

You intend **(1)**.  **(2)** is usually silly, but it is conceivable that it might occur somewhere, perhaps in some template code.  **(3)** and **(4)** are indeed the problems:  you can remove the `const` qualification and add the `volatile` qualification all with a single cast.

You could replace the existing `const_cast` with a pair of casts, `const_cast` and `volatile_cast`, and prohibit case **(2)**; then you could use either of them without the target type.  However, then it's more difficult to know the type of the cast expression.  To know whether a cast expression adds or removes qualification, you have to know what the type of the source expression is.

There's no reason you couldn't use a function template to get what you want:

```
template <typename T>
T* remove_const(const T* p) {
    return const_cast<T*>(p);
}
```

You could easily write similar functions for `remove_volatile` and for `add_const` and `add_volatile`, which are both implicit.

Comment: Of course the operator also allows `const_cast<>(&b)` (where b is not `const`) and the same set of resultant types, so even if it didn't handle volatility, you would have to ask Alexandros whether const_cast<> should toggle constness or default to adding or removing it (the latter would make it a bit of a misnomer).  As you say, in templates it's often desirable to get a const or non-const type without knowing what you started with.

Comment: @Tony: good point about b not needing to be const. More generally, even though I knew that const_cast can also add const, my implicit assumption is that nobody does that (since there are other ways to do it), therefore if the input b is not const you just let it be.

Comment: @Alexandros: Which other ways of adding const do you have in mind?  Say you have a non-const variable `std::string x`, and you want to call `fn(x)` but make sure `fn` can't accept `x` by non-const reference, you can currently write `fn(const_cast<const std::string&>(x));`.  It's a bit verbose, but what's better?

Comment: @Tony:  `static_cast` is preferable here because while it can add constness, it explicitly cannot remove constness.  Alternatively, it is common to write an `implicit_cast` function template along the lines of `template <typename T, typename U> T implicit_cast(U x) { return x; }`.

Comment: @James: have to disagree there - `static_cast<>` can change much more than just const/volatile qualifiers, to my mind - choosing it over `const_cast<>` implies intent to do so. Even if originally implemented correctly, if the type changes `static_cast<>` may continue to compile but do something other-than/beyond what was intended. In that respect, it becomes an unnecessary point of maintenance.  Same for your `implicit_cast<>` suggestion.

Comment: @Tony: though this doesn't constitute proof, James is in good company on this. In Item 3 of Scott Meyers' Effective C++, 3rd ed. he does precisely that (use static_cast for adding const) and states: "The cast that adds const is just forcing a safe conversion (from a non-const object to a const one), so we use a static_cast for that. The one that removes const can be accomplished only via a const_cast, so we don't really have a choice there."

Comment: @Alexandros: very interesting - emphasising static_cast<>s as "safe" versus const_cast<> being able to remove safety (albeit only if casting to non-const) - I still consider my reasoning above more compelling, as unintended type conversions between generally convertible types are not necessarily "safe" in every context, and certainly aren't what's intended in my example.

Comment: @Tony:  The `const_cast` carries the same risk:  you may inadvertently remove `volatile` qualification where you only intend to remove `const` qualification.  `const_cast` should be used only to remove qualification; this way it stands out in source code more readily.  The benefit of `implicit_cast` is that it is 100% safe; you can't perform any conversions with it other than those that would otherwise be allowed without any cast.

Comment: @James: good point - could remove volatile - but for many problem domains there's ten thousand non-`volatile` variables for each legitimately `volatile` one.  Agree not so for hardware and signal handling.  Effectively, `const_cast<const ...>` tells me "guaranteeing const". Unintended conversions - that might result in a different overload/instantiation of `fn()` being called, are something I want emphasised - `static_cast<>` warns me of that. Otherwise, we're rehashing the same ground, and seem to have reached the "agree to differ" threshold.

Answer (score 1):

I think James McNellis already touched on the important reasons. `const_cast`can both *add* and remove constness/volatileness. It's not always clear what you want.

If I call `const_cast` on an argument of type `const foo`, does that mean I want to make it non-`const`, or add  `volatile` to it? Or should it perhaps just *keep* the `const`qualifier? If I call it on an object of type (non-const) `foo`, should it add const? Or should it assume that I wanted to remove const-ness, and return an object of type (non-const) `foo` as well?

Another reason may simply be consistency.

We have `static_cast<T>(x)`, `dynamic_cast<T>(x)`, `reinterpret_cast<T>(x)` so it'd look odd to have a `const_cast(x)` without the template-like syntax.

Comment: Regarding *adding* const: OK, but that just displaces the question (since you can add const in other ways) making it "why does const_cast need to allow you to add const?".

Comment: Regarding consistency: yes, indeed, that is a legitimate point.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that using `const_cast` you can cast from

```
Foo * const * volatile * *
```

to

```
Foo * * * volatile * const
```

Is it really obvious what the destination type is?