# Why can template parameter be deduced only in one case?

Tags: c++, stl

Why does the following code compile for the line using a **non-const iterator** but fails for the **const iterator** (using Visual Studio 2008) ?

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> test;

    test.push_back(1);
    test.push_back(2);

    vector<int>::const_iterator cit = test.end();
    std::distance(test.begin(), cit); // error: template parameter is ambiguous

    vector<int>::iterator it = test.end();
    std::distance(test.begin(), it);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: In Visual Studio 2008 there is no vector member function `cbegin()` to avoid the ambiguousness, but an overloaded `begin()` method:

```
iterator begin()
    {   // return iterator for beginning of mutable sequence
    return (iterator(_Myfirst, this));
    }

const_iterator begin() const
    {   // return iterator for beginning of nonmutable sequence
    return (const_iterator(_Myfirst, this));
    }
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb you'll find that you need to use an `iterator` rather than a `const_iterator` in most cases - see [Effective STL](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-STL-Specific-Standard-Template/dp/0201749629) #26 for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: In Visual Studio 2008 there is no vector member function `cbegin()` to avoid the ambiguousness, but an overloaded `begin()` method:

I think the compiler *always* picks the non-const overload for a non-const objects, and the const method only for const objects.

Calling

```
std::distance(test.begin(), cit);
```

*doesn't* look at the overload set for `begin` and the type of `cit`, and figure out whether it can make a match. It resolves the overload first (to the non-const version), and hence fails.

The cleanest way to express your intent that will also work for the compiler is probably:

```
vector<int> const &cref = test;
vector<int>::const_iterator cit = cref.end();
std::distance(cref.begin(), cit);
```

Comment: Your calling example should be `std::distance(test.begin(), cit)` to match my example, shouldn't it? But very good explanation, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm deliberately calling `begin` on the const reference, to force selection of the const overload

Answer (score 2):

The template `distance` takes one single argument, `distance<T>(T first, T last)`. Since `test.begin()` has type `iterator` and `cit` has type `const_iterator`, the template argument cannot be deduced.

You can either use `test.cbegin()` to get a guaranteed `const_iterator`, or otherwise say `static_cast<std::vector<int> const &>(test).begin()`.

(This is the same as if you had `max<T>(T x, T y)` and tried to say `max(1, 2U)` -- it wouldn't compile because it's ambiguous.)

Comment: See my note: there is no cbegin() in Visual Studio 2008 vector implementation.

Comment: I always believed that adding/removing constness is reserved to `const_cast`, not `static_cast`.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: Only **removing** CV qualifiers requires a `const_cast`. Adding constness is a perfectly permissible conversion.

Comment: @KerrekSB Technically yes. But still `const_cast` is superior because ensures that no other changes in type will happen and clearly shows your intentions.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec:  Actually, since the conversion is implicit, `implicit_cast` would be best.  See an example implementation in [a comment I made to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383776/151292).  Alternatively, one could write a trivial `make_const` function template that const-qualifies its argument.  `const_cast` is dangerous and should only be used for _adding_ cv-qualification.

Answer (score 0):

The function template `std::distance` only takes a single template
argument, which must be the same for both function arguments.  The
return type of `test.begin()` is simply `iterator`, not
`const_iterator`, so the types of the function arguments are different.
The compiler deduces `std::vector<int>::iterator` for the first, and
`std::vector<int>::const_iterator` for the second, so the deduction
fails.  Template argument deduction does *not* take into account
possible conversions, except for the simplest conversions.

There are many ways to work around thing, but they all have noticeable
drawbacks.  (That's probably why the committee added the `cbegin` and
`cend` functions.)  For the moment, your best bet is probably just to forgo the `const`, and use `iterator` for both.

Comment: I'm confused: the return type of begin() is _either_ const_iterator _or_ iterator (see my note in the question). So the types of both arguments _don't_ differ necessarily.

Comment: @nabulke `begin` called on const object returns `const_iterator`. On non-const one returns `iterator`.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: Ah, thanks for your comment! This was the missing link to help me understand this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`distance` must have template arguments of the same time. In this case it is `_Vector_const_iterator`. There are two overloads of `begin`: const and non-const. const-version produces `_Vector_const_iterator`, but another produces `_Vector_iterator`. `_Vector_iterator` inherits from `_Vector_const_iterator`.

So, both const and non-const overloads of `begin` are capable of producing `_Vector_const_iterator` and they both can be picked for non-const object, i.e. compiler gets confused.

This is how I got it to compile:

```
    std::distance(((const vector<int>&)test).begin(), cit);
```

Comment: But why isn't the compiler confused for _both_ examples?

Comment: because if you use non-const iterator for second parameter to distance, then compiler is allowed to pick only non-const version of begin()